# Using void * in C in place of overloading?

Tags: c, function, void-pointers

My question here is I had seen code like this for a multithreading application:

```
void Thread( void* pParams )
{  
    int *milliseconds = (int *)pParams;
    Sleep(milliseconds);
    printf("Finished after %d milliseconds", milliseconds); //or something like that
}
```

This greatly took my interest, I knew `malloc` sends back a void pointer and you can cast it to what you want, does this mean that I can create a function that can accept any data type?

For example a function I wrote without testing:

```
void myfunc( void* param )
{  
    switch(sizeof(param)) {
       case 1:
       char *foo = (char *)param; break;
       case 2:
       short *foo = (short *)param; break;
       case 4: 
       int *foo = (int *)param; break;
    }
}
myfunc(3.1415);
myfunc(0);
myfunc('a');
```

I may be completely wrong, even if this does work is it horrible practise? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

yes, `void *` is great for the creation of generic functions. However, once you pass a pointer to a certain datatype to a function that takes a `void *` you lose all type information.  One way to steer your program so it knows which type you passed in is to have a 2nd parameter of type `enum` which may have values such as INT, FLOAT, DOUBLE etc. etc.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef enum inputTypes
{
    INT,
    DOUBLE,
    CHAR
} inType;

void myfunc(void*, inType);

int main(void)
{
    int    i = 42;
    double d = 3.14;
    char   c = 'a';

    myfunc(&i, INT);
    myfunc(&d, DOUBLE);
    myfunc(&c, CHAR);

    return 0;
}

void myfunc(void* param, inType type)
{  
    switch(type) {
       case INT:
           printf("you passed in int %d\n", *((int *)param));
           break;
       case DOUBLE:
           printf("you passed in double %lf\n", *((double *)param));
           break; 
       case CHAR: 
           printf("you passed in char %c\n", *((char *)param));
           break;
    }
}
```

#### Output

```
you passed in int 42
you passed in double 3.140000
you passed in char a
```

Comment: Ah! I was trying to understand what you meant, but this example really makes sense! Thank you for writing it! :) I'll try to write this from scratch and play around to learn more.

Comment: This reminds me varargs, like in printf(), where the first argument indicates what are the others.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it is possible to create a function that accepts multiple type, but that is not how you do it.

In your `myfunc`, `sizeof(param)` will always be the same: `sizeof` is determined at compile time, and will be the size of a pointer.

The reason it works for threads, it generally it is known by the coder what the pointer points to, at compile time, and all you need is a simple cast. If you don't know at compile time what the `void *` points to, you must pass it at runtime somehow.

The key with `void *`: You can only cast them back to whatever they were in the first place, and it is up to you to know what that is. A simple `void *` by itself cannot tell you what it is pointing to.

Comment: Ah, this makes total sense. I see some use in doing what I was thinking, but not in many instances. I guess I'll just keep it in my useless bag of C tricks -- I understand more about pointers atleast!

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof(param)` will always return the size of a pointer, so presumably 8 if you are on a 64-bit system. This has nothing to do with what it's pointing to.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't work because `sizeof(param)` is trying to take the size of a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

The size of a `void*` is completely dependent on the system and determined at compile time, not on what is actually contained within it.